# Андроид. 2 одинаковых изображения в приложении "прыгают"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Есть приложение на Андроиде, разработано через Xamarin Forms. В нем есть картинка которая показывается при старте приложения (SplashScreen) и страница авторизации, на которой представлена таже картинка.
получается что в на странице авторизации картинка смещается вниз, это бросается в глаза.

Для SplashScreen, в файле styles.xml

```
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
     <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>    
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/SplashScreen</item>
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
    </style>
```

В Xaml страница авторизации

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        <Image x:Name="FonIMG" Source="SplashScreen.png" Aspect="Fill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{OnPlatform Android='0.5,0.25,0.8,0.4',iOS='0.5,0.5,0.8,0.4' }" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HeightRequest="200">       
        <StackLayout >            
                <StackLayout Padding="5">             
                <ActivityIndicator x:Name="Indicator" Color="Red"/>                      
                <Entry x:Name="Entry_User" Placeholder="Табельный номер"  TextColor="Black"/>                      
                <Entry x:Name="Entry_Pass" Placeholder="Пароль"  TextColor="Black"/>                       
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="Запомнить меня"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="Small" TextColor="DarkBlue"/>
                            <Switch x:Name="SaveMe" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" IsToggled="True" />
                        </Grid>
                </StackLayout>                
            </StackLayout>        
            <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Text="Войти" Clicked="BtnLogin_Clicked" TextColor="DarkBlue" FontSize="Medium"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>        
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Ниже на скринах показано как отображается
[image: SplashScreen]
[image: Авторизация]

Если посмотрите на изображения, логотип на втором скрине расположен ниже.
Пробовал в xaml пробовать менять значения Aspect но результат тоже не удовлетворил. Не пойму что нужно сделать, чтобы изображения не менялись (не прыгали)

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится. Сделал пока следующим образом, ввел дополнительно xml, в котором:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="#000000"/>”
  </item>
  <item android:top="25dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/SplashScreen"/>  
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

а в файле styles.xml, своей темы, прописал ссылку на этот xml

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
```